# How to share a bit bucket repository with another user?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using Bit bucket and I have a friend that I would like to share my repository with. I am using the free individual account. There seems to be an option of creating a team in bit bucket but it says it will convert my account from individual to team account. I do not want that. How can I give another user access to this repository?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is an option of share link, if you click on that, a popup will be appeared on that you can give your friends username or his email to share the repository. This popup says something like
"Existing users are granted access to this repository immediately. New users will be sent an invitation."

**UPDATE**: Looks like the interface is slightly changed. You can share a repo via Settings / Access management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ashok. I figured it out but you answered it so you deserve the points.

Comment: This account (...) is at its plan limit and will need to be upgraded before adding more users.

Comment: Is this still working? I can't find a way to generate an access link to the repo. I need to host some private code that I need to send to an interviewer. Asking their bitbucket credentials is not an option.

Comment: does one need to add the invited user's public key?

Answer (score 27):

1. (Optional first step) Have your friend register an own account on Bitbucket.
2. Visit your repository on the Bitbucket website.
3. On the “Overview” page, on the right side, click “Invite users to this repo”.
4. If your friend register in step 1, enter his user name, otherwise just enter the email and he will get a mail with a link to register.
5. Afterwards, your friend will have access to your repository using his own Bitbucket credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Simply go to `admin/access` endpoint.

eg.

`https://bitbucket.org/YOU_USERNAME/YOUR_PROJECT/admin/access`

Answer (score 0):

I added users to my repository by navigating to "settings->Repository permissions".

Answer (score 0):

You can grant your friend read-only access through ssh. In other words, he/she can clone your repository but cannot push to the remote repository. For this purpose, you need to add its public key to access keys.