# git clone with custom key/.ssh/config works on one machine, not other

Tags: git, ssh

On a XUbuntu 16.04 machine,
I have this setup for a repository on bitbucket

.ssh/config

```
Host bitbucket.org-infoodle
Hostname bitbucket.org
User jochen
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa-bb_infoodle2
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

I check out the got repository with

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org-infoodle:richinnz/infoodle-web.git
```

This works fine.

However on a 2nd machine, with a different key, I get the following log:

```
Cloning into 'infoodle-web'...
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/jochen/.ssh/id_rsa-bb_infoodle type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/jochen/.ssh/id_rsa-bb_infoodle-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.314-df0526e app-130
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.314-df0526e app-130
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/jochen/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/jochen/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/jochen/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/jochen/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/jochen/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/jochen/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 104.192.143.3
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/jochen/.ssh/known_hosts:22
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: jochen-windows (0x55c97a2fa170), agent
debug2: key: /home/jochen/.ssh/id_rsa-bb_infoodle (0x55c97a2fa0a0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: jochen-windows
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:JiGG4lMVcyq8MOzTMskuOZ7ww6maX6wjpMVjW76t9+Q
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:JiGG4lMVcyq8MOzTMskuOZ7ww6maX6wjpMVjW76t9+Q
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([104.192.143.3]:22).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'richinnz/infoodle-web.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 26
repository access denied.
debug2: channel 0: written 26 to efd 7
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2716, received 1736 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5139.0, received 3284.7
debug1: Exit status 1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I compared permissions on .ssh/config and private/ public keys, but could not find any differences. Any other ideas of what could be my problem?

Comment: Have you registered the ssh key of the second server with your bitbucket.org repo as a known deployment key?

Comment: PS,  if you copied the key files from one server to another, be sure to run ssh key-add to properly register it on the second server.

Comment: Different Bitbucket user with different (less) repository permissions?

Answer (score 1):

First, your config file should list `git` as a user, not a username.

Second, you are authenticated, but that user does not have access to the repo you want:

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([104.192.143.3]:22).
repository access denied.
```

Check the identity you are using in BitBucket from your second machine with:

```
ssh -T git@bitbucket.org-infoodle
```

That account is likely [not declared in the admin part of the target repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077315/6309).